# Horizontal Scroll View One Child(Eclipse IDE, Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

I realize there many related problems, but I'm looking for this specific answer. The below code is my XML for my mainactivity in an app. Now my question. I would like to be able to alter the contents of the horizontal view, dynamically. This will involve clearing it of Views as well as adding new ones. How exactly do I go about doing this, as well as accessing the Linear Layout within it, when I tried to assign an ID to the Linear Layout  I was given an error saying it could not accept a id of type string.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txtClassification"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:text="Classification:&lt;>"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
           tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/spinGoto"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnBack"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:text="Go Back"
           tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnSelect"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Select"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtClassification"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinGoto"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtClassification" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will **have to** work with the `LinearLayout` because a `HorizontalScrollView` can only have one direct child.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtClassification" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yourLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Then you access it programmatically to add or remove views

```
public void addView(View v) {
    LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
    yourLayout.addView(v);
}

public void clearLayout() {
    LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
    yourLayout.removeAllViews();
}

public void removeView(View v) {
    LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
    yourLayout.removeView(v);
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The id has a predifined format. Enter the name you want after the `"@+id/"` syntax. Example `android:id="@+id/layout"`.

Then in code get the LinearLayoutinside of the HorizontalScrollView:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

To add a View to layout call the **adView()** of your layout. Example:

```
//add 5 buttons
for (int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++){
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setId(i);
btn.setText(i+"");
layout.addView(btn);
}
```

To remove a View from the layout call **removeView()**

```
//remove button nr. 3
Button btn3 = layout.findViewById(3);
layout.removeView(btn3);
```

The HorizontalScrollView takes care of everything, you just have to populate and organize the elements inside the nested LinearLayout.

Good luck!